The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method in objective-c in iOS , Xcode 15
We are using AWS-IOS-SDK to upload images and text.
error occurred in Xcode 15 but working good in Xcode 14 ,we used the same source code for both versions.
Please check the error message
AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:263 | -[AWSXMLResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body: [
SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.AWERFJUIOLPRTBDUTYAWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20240702T113658Z
20240702/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
5526a3fb62da4bea59eeb780deef64e9d943168388e7bfed6e2f47335fb6a1878d45a2e2d81869e6b734bc4cf9a95717df7286c41fb84e842d79d0e5be3ca7a641 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 34 30 37 30 32 54 31 31 33 36 35 38 5a 0a 32 30 32 34 30 37 30 32 2f 75 73 2d 65 61 73 74 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 35 35 32 36 61 33 66 62 36 32 64 61 34 62 65 61 35 39 65 65 62 37 38 30 64 65 65 66 36 34 65 39 64 39 34 33 31 36 38 33 38 38 65 37 62 66 65 64 36 65 32 66 34 37 33 33 35 66 62 36 61 31 38 37PUT
Thank you for your help support.
